# When row is empty in PHP it should not display anything. When there is something in it, it should display input

Tags: php, mysqli

```
function getConnection() {
$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','shop');
if($con->connect_errno!=0){return null;};
$con->query("SET NAMES utf8");
return $con;}

function getRed(){
$con = getConnection();
$sql = "SELECT red FROM colors;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
if($row["red"] == ""){
echo "";
}else{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<input type='image' src=" . $row["red"]. ">";
}
mysqli_close($con);}}
```

In PHP I have row "red" filled with link to MShirt/redshirt.png. This code should create an input with this image but if is empty shouldn't create input. Now, this doesn't work even with a filled row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `mysqli_num_rows()` returns only the count of results returned by your query, the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is the one going through the results. I would suggest taking the `mysqli_close($con);` outside the if statement as shown.

```
<?php
function getConnection() {
$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','shop');
if($con->connect_errno!=0){return null;};
$con->query("SET NAMES utf8");
return $con;}

function getRed(){
    $con = getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT red FROM colors;";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    if($rowCount > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            if(isset($row["red"]) && $row["red"] != "") {
                 echo "<input type='image' src=" . $row["red"]. ">";
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems with your code, but the main one is that `mysqli_num_rows()` does not return data. It tells you how many records were fetched from the database into PHP.

- You don't need `mysqli_num_rows()` in your code.
- You don't need `mysqli_close($con);`, especially not inside of the loop.
- You don't need the `while` loop. This is an old way of iterating. Use `foreach` instead.
- You don't need `if/else` and `echo ""`. You only need the positive condition.

Here is your code fixed:

```
function getConnection() {
    // enabler error reporting, create an instance and set the correct charset
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'shop');
    $con->set_charset('utf8mb4');
    return $con;
}

function getRed() {
    $con = getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT red FROM colors;";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        if ($row["red"] != "") {
            echo "<input type='image' src=" . $row["red"] . ">";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...better put this answer at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this input should work for, but I assume you want to simply embed an image. Use it like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<img src="' . $row['red']. '" />';
}
```

mysqli_num_rows is used to count how many rows are in the result, it returns the number of rows which you can not read like an array...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $row_count.' rows in result.';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo '<img src="' . $row['red']. '" />';
}
```

Please make sure to understand basic HTML before getting into PHP and MySQL, also do not do database queries without getting to know proper security standards.

Comment: This wasnt necessarily what I wanted to do. In database i have rows with colors. Every color have text "MShirt/colorshirt.png" (Catalog / Picture). I need get this text and put in <input type="image" src=" HERE">. But not every color have text with catalog and image, i want only show this with catalog and image. So function must get data from rows. And if they had text put it in <input type="image" src="HERE"> . If no text doesn't create input that's why i used echo " ";. We didn't understand each other but u have a lot of knowledge.  
If you understand now what I want to achieve, please help